# Connect 3.5 hard disk with HP probook USB type c port

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I am trying to connect 3.5 hard disk. to my HP Probook 450 G4 laptop via 2.5 portable hard converter circuit and usb cable. laptop USB 2.0 and USB 3.0. But it did not work and i think it is due to low of power supply. My laptop have USB type C port which compromised of the USB power delivery or PD.

<https://support.hp.com/hk-en/document/c04723006

Its confirmed the circuit i used to connect, cable used to connect circuit and usb 3.0 2.0 cable and usb ports are working fine.

My plan is to buy USB type C to usb 3.0 Cable and carry out the same procedure.

https://www.ugreen.com/products/usb-c-to-usb-3-0-otg-cable

Can someone correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a proper 3.5" adapter or complete hard drive enclosure [like this one](https://www.ugreen.com/products/3-5-usb-3-0-hard-drive-enclosure) with a separate power supply. A 2.5" solution won't work on a 3.5" drive, it doesn't provide enough power.

Comment: @imply can't we get enough power through USB type C since it supports PD

Comment: @HarshaMadusanka Not with a simple USB-C cable, which carries only 5V, while a 3.5" HDD requires 12V.

Comment: HP PROBOOK 450 g4 USB TYPE C port support 12v power. Is not it

Comment: @HarshaMadusanka USB-PD requires negotiation between chips on both sides to provide voltages >5V. A simple USB-C to USB adapter cable doesn't work. There's also no pin for 12V in regular USB connectors.

Comment: If you don't trust my answers, read this: https://superuser.com/questions/1489467/sata-to-usb-3-5-hard-drive-using-only-usb-power

Comment: @Imoly Thanks you very much for the support extended. Will follow your advices as well

Answer (score 0):

What kind of interface is on the hard drive?  Is it PATA (parallel ATA)?  If so then I believe I see the problem.  The 2.5" PATA connector provides data and power, the 3.5" PATA connector does not provide power.  If you are using a USB to 2.5" PATA drive adapter, using an additional adapter to connect this to a 3.5" PATA drive, but not providing power to the drive by some other means then the drive simply is not getting power.  Connecting the USB to PATA adapter to USB-C will not correct the problem.